# What does the OpenGL core profile version string mean?

Tags: version, opengl

This is the output from glxinfo for my machine:

```
$ glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.1
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Does that mean my card only supports OpenGL up to 3.0? What does the 4.1 "core profile" version mean? I've got a Sapphire Radeon R7 250X which should support up to OpenGL 4.3 according to its online specs.

Could this be a driver issue? I'm on arch linux and I have xf86-video-ati installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in Mesa or OpenGL but according to the release notes of Mesa [here](http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/11.1.0.html) then version 11.1 (and 11.2 also) only implements OpenGL up to version 4.1. So no matter if your card can do 4.3, Mesa will only use 4.1 I think.